# awk '/range start/,/range end/' within script

Tags: awk

How do I use the awk range pattern `'/begin regex/,/end regex/'` within a self-contained awk script?

To clarify, given program csv.awk:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
FS = "\"" 
}

/TREE/,/^$/
{
  line="";
        for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
                if (i != 2) line=line $i;
        }

        split(line, v, ",");
        if (v[5] ~ "FOAM") {
                print NR, v[5];
        }
}
```

and file chunk:

```
TREE
10362900,A,INSTL - SEAL,Revise
,10362901,A,ASSY / DETAIL - PANEL,Revise
,,-203,ASSY - PANEL,Qty -,Add
,,,-309,PANEL,Qty 1,Add
,,,,"FABRICATE FROM TEKLAM NE1G1-02-250 PER TPS-CN-500, TYPE A"
,,,-311,PANEL,Qty 1,Add
,,,,"FABRICATE FROM TEKLAM NE1G1-02-750 PER TPS-CN-500, TYPE A"
,,,-313,FOAM SEAL,1.00 X 20.21 X .50 THK,Qty 1,Add
,,,,"BMS1-68, GRADE B, FORM II, COLOR BAC706 (BLACK)"
,,,-315,FOAM SEAL,1.50 X 8.00 X .25 THK,Qty 1,Add
,,,,"BMS1-68, GRADE B, FORM II, COLOR BAC706 (BLACK)"
,PN HERE,Dual Lock,Add
,
10442900,IR,INSTL - SEAL,Update (not released)
,10362901,A,ASSY / DETAIL - PANEL,Revise
,PN HERE,Dual Lock,Add
```

I want to have this output:

```
27 FOAM SEAL
29 FOAM SEAL
```

What is the syntax for adding the command line form `'/begin regex/,/end regex/'` to the script to operate on those lines only? All my attempts lead to syntax errors and googling only gives me the cli form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
FS = "\"" 
}

/from/,/to/ {
  line="";
        for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
                if (i != 2) line=line $i;
        }

        split(line, v, ",");
        if (v[5] ~ "FOAM") {
                print NR, v[5];
        }
}
```

If the `from` `to` regexes are dynamic:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
    FS = "\"" 
    FROM=ARGV[1]
    TO=ARGV[2]
    if (ARGC == 4) { # the pattern was the only thing, so force read from standard input                   
       ARGV[1] = "-"
    } else {
       ARGV[1] = ARGV[3] 
    }
}

{ if ($0 ~ FROM) { p = 1 ; l = 0} }
{ if ($0 ~ TO)   { p = 0 ; l = 1} } 

{  
  if (p == 1 || l == 1) {
   line="";
        for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
                if (i != 2) line=line $i;
        }

        split(line, v, ",");
        if (v[5] ~ "FOAM") {
                print NR, v[5];
        }
   l = 0 } 
}
```

Now you have to call it like: `./scriptname.awk "FROM_REGEX" "TO_REGEX" INPUTFILE`. The last param is optional, if missing `STDIN` can be used.

HTH

Comment: and now make "from" and "to" dynamic, OP wants to feed that from command line.

Comment: I'm sorry but where was that mentioned? Anyway, editing the solution.

Comment: it would be a pitty to change the script just to change the 'from' and 'to' range, wouldn't it? :)

Comment: in your first example (which is closer to my request), adding the regex at that location prints unfiltered output from /from/ to the first line v[5] appears on, then prints NR, v[5]. I only want to print NR, v[5].

Comment: @ZsoltBotykai: /me looks at my simpler one liner. throwing more complexity at a problem is not always the smartest thing to do.

Comment: I wasn't familiar enough with the treatment of newlines in awk scripts. When I changed "/TREE/,/^$/ \n {" to "/TREE/,/^$/ {" I got the output I was looking for. Thank you VERY much for your help Zsolt.

Comment: @akira you are right. I did not said that your solution is wrong. It works. It "just" starts one more process. And sometimes it's better not to do that. 
amorphousone: you're welcome.

Answer (score 4):

why not use 2 steps:

```
% awk '/start/,/end/' < input.csv | awk csv.awk
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to show us what you have tried. Is there something about /begin regex/ or /end regex/ you're not telling us, other wise your script with the additions should work, i.e.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
FS = "\"" 
}

/begin regex/,/end regex/{
  line="";
        for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
                if (i != 2) line=line $i;
        }

        split(line, v, ",");
        if (v[5] ~ "FOAM") {
                print NR, v[5];
        }
}
```

OR are you using an old Unix, where there is old awk as /usr/bin/awk and New awk as /usr/bin/nawk. Also see if you have /usr/xpg4/bin/awk or gawk (path could be anything).

Finally, show us the error messages you are getting.

I hope this helps.